# MediaFire direct link in Python?

Tags: python, download, mediafire

I'm making a package management utility for Minecraft mods, a lot of which are
distributed using MediaFire. I'd like to be able to download the mod files directly off
MediaFire. I tried poking around in the page source, but I don't know enough HTML or Javascript for that to be useful. How would I go about downloading a file off MediaFire given the URL for the download page?

Comment: You have to evaluate JavaScript from Python. That's not too difficult, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356948/scraping-javascript-driven-web-pages-with-pyqt4-how-to-access-pages-that-need-a or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630214/download-html-of-url-with-python-but-with-javascript-enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It starts and ends with reading [MediaFire Acceptable Use Policy](http://www.mediafire.com/acceptable_use_policy.php)

> You agree while using MediaFire Services, that you may not:
>
> Use the
>   Services for any illegal purpose;
>
> Use any robot, spider, site search and/or retrieval application, or
>   other device to retrieve or index any portion of the Services, with
>   the exception of public search engines;

Answer (score 1):

I know its been 2 years, but had to do just that.
Here is the code.

below code requires **selenium** and **phantomjs**

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = "http://www.mediafire.com/download/X/Y.pdf"
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get(url)
div = driver.find_element_by_class_name('download_link')
print div.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
driver.quit()
```